# pandas: add column with values from previous time points

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df` with time series data of non-regular and spotty (yearly) data. It contains a column for the year, the country, and two values, like this:

```
pd.DataFrame(columns = ["_year", "_country", "val1_t1", "val2_t1"],
         data = [   [1996, "AUSTRALIA",         0.3870, 0.2570],
                    [1996, "NEW ZEALAND",       0.1120, 0.3390],
                    [1996, "UNITED STATES",     0.1264, 0.2515],
                    [1997, "UNITED KINGDOM",    0.4433, 0.3145],
                    [2002, "NEW ZEALAND",       0.4126, 0.2093],
                    [2004, "AUSTRALIA",         0.3764, 0.3610],
                    [2004, "UNITED STATES",     0.4152, 0.2610],
                    [2005, "UNITED KINGDOM",    0.3614, 0.3323],
                    [2007, "AUSTRALIA",         0.4338, 0.3628],
                    [2008, "NEW ZEALAND",       0.0091, 0.4493],
                    [2008, "UNITED STATES",     0.7980, 0.3584],
                    [2011, "NEW ZEALAND",       0.0108, 0.4731],
                    [2012, "UNITED STATES",     0.6874, 0.4710],
                    [2013, "AUSTRALIA",         0.3338, 0.4094],
                    [2014, "NEW ZEALAND",       0.0142, 0.4704],
                    [2015, "UNITED KINGDOM",    0.3118, 0.3778]])
```

I would now like to add two more columns, `val1_t0` and `val2_t0`, with the values of that country for the previous time point. I have a dictionary with the respective previous year per country:

```
t_1 = {"AUSTRALIA" : {2013: 2007, 2007: 2004, 2004: 1996, 1996: -99},
       "NEW ZEALAND" : {2014: 2011, 2011: 2008, 2008: 2002, 2002: 1996, 1996: -99},
       "UNITED STATES" : {2012: 2008, 2008: 2004, 2004: 1996, 1996: -99},
       "UNITED KINGDOM" : {2015: 2005, 2005: 1997, 1997: -99}}
```

The desired outcome is a `df` where the row, e.g. `UNITED KINGDOM` in `2015` has two additional columns, where `val1_t0` is `val1_t1` from the previous entry (here: `UNITED KINGDOM` in `2005`), like this:

```
pd.DataFrame(columns = ["_year", "_country", "val1_t1", "val2_t1", 'val1_t0', 'val2_t0'],
         data = [   [1996, "AUSTRALIA",         0.3870, 0.2570, np.nan, np.nan],  # AU < 1996 non-existent
                    [1996, "NEW ZEALAND",       0.1120, 0.3390, np.nan, np.nan],  # NZ < 1996 non-existent
                    [1996, "UNITED STATES",     0.1264, 0.2515, np.nan, np.nan],  # US < 1996 non-existent
                    [1997, "UNITED KINGDOM",    0.4433, 0.3145, np.nan, np.nan],  # UK < 1997 non-existent
                    [2002, "NEW ZEALAND",       0.4126, 0.2093, 0.1120, 0.3390],  # NZ 1996
                    [2004, "AUSTRALIA",         0.3764, 0.3610, 0.3870, 0.2570],  # AU 1996
                    [2004, "UNITED STATES",     0.4152, 0.2610, 0.1264, 0.2515],  # US 1996
                    [2005, "UNITED KINGDOM",    0.3614, 0.3323, 0.4126, 0.2093],  # UK 1997
                    [2007, "AUSTRALIA",         0.4338, 0.3628, 0.3764, 0.3610],  # AU 2004
                    [2008, "NEW ZEALAND",       0.0091, 0.4493, 0.4126, 0.2093],  # NZ 2002
                    [2008, "UNITED STATES",     0.7980, 0.3584, 0.4152, 0.2610],  # US 2004
                    [2011, "NEW ZEALAND",       0.0108, 0.4731, 0.0091, 0.4493],  # NZ 2008
                    [2012, "UNITED STATES",     0.6874, 0.4710, 0.7980, 0.3584],  # US 2008
                    [2013, "AUSTRALIA",         0.3338, 0.4094, 0.4338, 0.3628],  # AU 2007
                    [2014, "NEW ZEALAND",       0.0142, 0.4704, 0.0108, 0.4731],  # NZ 2011
                    [2015, "UNITED KINGDOM",    0.3118, 0.3778, 0.3614, 0.3323]]) # UK 2005
```

Does someone have an elegant implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`groupby` and `shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) should do what you are looking for. Not sure of the use of your dictionary as this method won't be affected if years are missing. Ensure that the years are sorted with `sort_values` before

```
df[["val1_t0", "val2_t0"]] = (df.sort_values('_year')
                                .groupby('_country')[["val1_t1", "val2_t1"]].shift())

print(df)
    _year        _country  val1_t1  val2_t1  val1_t0  val2_t0
0    1996       AUSTRALIA   0.3870   0.2570      NaN      NaN
1    1996     NEW ZEALAND   0.1120   0.3390      NaN      NaN
2    1996   UNITED STATES   0.1264   0.2515      NaN      NaN
3    1997  UNITED KINGDOM   0.4433   0.3145      NaN      NaN
4    2002     NEW ZEALAND   0.4126   0.2093   0.1120   0.3390
5    2004       AUSTRALIA   0.3764   0.3610   0.3870   0.2570
6    2004   UNITED STATES   0.4152   0.2610   0.1264   0.2515
7    2005  UNITED KINGDOM   0.3614   0.3323   0.4433   0.3145
8    2007       AUSTRALIA   0.4338   0.3628   0.3764   0.3610
9    2008     NEW ZEALAND   0.0091   0.4493   0.4126   0.2093
10   2008   UNITED STATES   0.7980   0.3584   0.4152   0.2610
11   2011     NEW ZEALAND   0.0108   0.4731   0.0091   0.4493
12   2012   UNITED STATES   0.6874   0.4710   0.7980   0.3584
13   2013       AUSTRALIA   0.3338   0.4094   0.4338   0.3628
14   2014     NEW ZEALAND   0.0142   0.4704   0.0108   0.4731
15   2015  UNITED KINGDOM   0.3118   0.3778   0.3614   0.3323
```